# JS Effect in jQuery Mobile collapsible set (js not execute)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the execution of JavaScript within a collapsible-set. I want to run inside the collapsible-set some kind of carousel effect.

But unfortunately the code is executed only in the open tab. Opening the other tabs to see there is nothing. Although the initialization of the effect takes place for all elements.

Here you will find the Fiddle

With code: http://jsfiddle.net/2qVBN/4/
Fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/2qVBN/4/embedded/result/

There are also problems with the re-initialization of the code when you switch between portrait and landscape mode.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make sure that the code inside the collapsibles is always loaded and executed?

Thanks in advance
vis_dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here JS on the divs which are displayed none can not be applyed.
In your case I suggest, you can expand each of your collapsible div by js and apply js to that.

thats how you can expand your collapsible div.

```
$('div').trigger('expand');
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2qVBN/11/)

Comment: Thanks ABC,

it has brought me one step further.

I caught the expand-event and apply the js code there again.

The content is now displayed after switching tabs again. However, the carousel effect does not restart.

Do you have an idea?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2qVBN/9/
http://jsfiddle.net/2qVBN/9/embedded/result/

Comment: i added the jsfiddle example. I think you will find your answer by the help of that example.